# Looping an array of tables

Tags: lua

How can I loop this array of tables?

```
TASK_CONFIG = {
    [1] = {NAME = "1-a", COUNT = 10, REWARD = 1000},
    [2] = {NAME = "4-b", COUNT = 10, REWARD = 6000},
    [3] = {NAME = "3-a", COUNT = 15, REWARD = 2400},
}
```

I need something like:

```
for each ITEM in TASK_CONFIG
    for each FIELD in ITEM
        -- do something
    next
next
```

The idea is looping every field, for example:

Looping every row and getting the values "name", "count", "reward"

Comment: "*table of arrays*" That's not a table of arrays. A better description would be an array of tables. The array, with numbered keys, contains values which are tables, with non-numbered keys.

Comment: thank you, just solved going to answer myself

Answer (score 2):

```
for a, b in pairs(TASK_CONFIG) do
    for c, d in pairs(b) do
        -- print info / do something
    end
end
```